# Service Account Office 365 API/Azure

Tags: azure, office365

I'm currently looking into the Office 365 API. Is it possible to create a Service Account which will make calls to the API on behalf of an application and not a user?

Google has the following :
https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2#serviceaccount

Thanks

Thanks for getting back to me. Would it be possible to do the following using the API. I think it is from what I have read on another blog but just wanted to confirm this. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/exchangedev/archive/2014/03/25/using-oauth2-to-access-calendar-contact-and-mail-api-in-exchange-online-in-office-365.aspx   Could I log on using the Office 365 admin account and upload documents to users "onedrive for business" folders ie if I set the scopes outlined here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn776442(v=office.15).aspx Overall I want to be able to move users documents into office 365 without them having to do this. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for your interest in Office 365 APIs.  We don't yet have support for a Service Account to make Office 365 API calls on behalf of an application and not a user.  However, this is prioritized high on our roadmap and we are currently working on it.  We don't have a release date that we can share at this time but will update our Office 365 API documentation as soon as service account support is ready.

UPDATE: Sorry for delay in updating this answer but support for an app to access all users' mailboxes in an Office 365 tenant, as itself, using client credential flow has been available for some time.  See https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/exchangedev/2015/01/21/building-daemon-or-service-apps-with-office-365-mail-calendar-and-contacts-apis-oauth2-client-credential-flow/ for details.

Comment: I've updated my question with extra details as it wont let me add any additional text. Thanks

Comment: @Webfort: For future reference, that probably should have been a new question.

Comment: apologies, will create another a question

Comment: Yes, see my updated answer.  Sorry for the delay in responding to your question, I missed the notification.

Comment: Hi @VenkatAyyadevara-MSFT, how about read and write to a excel file in office 365 ? Can show me some sample how to do it ?